# Mongoose validate length of array in schema

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I want to create a schema, with arrays for names of participants at an event, I make the list of participants by doing so:

```
  quizPart:[{
    type:String,
  }]
```

How can I validate that the length of this array is either zero (no participants at this event) or 2, and not 1 (it is a two people per team event). I want to return an error message that I can handle with  `ValidationError`

I am adding data to this schema like so:

```
var school = new School();
school.quizPart=req.body.quiz;
```

where `req.body.quiz = ["name1","name2"]` or `['','']`

and then, if only 1 field has a string value, I want to parse an error to the repsonse body like so:

```
    function handleValidationError(err, body) {
      for (field in err.errors) {
        switch (err.errors[field].path) {
          case "quizPart":
            body["quizPartError"] = err.errors[field].message;
            break; 
}}}
```

Comment: You can write a mongoose hook on pre update

Comment: @KunalMukherjee how exactly can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the field:

```
  quizPart:[{
    type:String,
  }],
```

And then verified the field by:

```
schoolSchema.path('quizPart').validate((list)=>{
  alNumRegex= /^[a-z0-9]+$/i
  return list[0]!=="" && list[1]!=="" || alNumRegex.test(list[0]) && alNumRegex.test(list[1]);
},'Please Register atleast two participants for quiz.');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of what I mean to say.

Write a [`pre('update')`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre) mongoose hook and inspect the `$set` object if the `quizParts` field has length 0 or 2 or not.

**index.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const test = require('./test');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test2', {useNewUrlParser: true});
mongoose.set('debug',true);
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
});

(async() => {
    try {
        const testUpdate = test();
        const updateQuery = {
            $set: {
                quizPart: [
                    {
                        type: 'Type 1'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'Type 2'
                    }
                ]
            }
        };
        const updateResult = await testUpdate.update({}, updateQuery).exec();
    } catch(err) {
        console.error(err);    
    }
})();
```

---

test.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

module.exports = function() {   
    const testSchema = new Schema({
        quizPart: [
            {
                type: String,
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        collection: 'test',
        timestamps: true
    });

    testSchema.pre('update', function(next) {
        const update = this._update.$set;

        if (update.length === 0 || update.length === 2) {
            return next();
        }
        else {
            return next(new Error('Cannot have length 1!'));
        }
    });
    
    return mongoose.model('test', testSchema);
};
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but I am sorry I can't really understand what you did here as I am new to mongoose and haven't used the `$set` object you are talking about to set my `quizParts` to a value, I have edited my question, so that you know whats going on in my code.